# How to detect when TextEditor is focused (tapped)

Tags: swiftui

I have a custom `TextField` where I detect when the user taps on it to change the look of the field, but I tried to add the same look for the `TextEditor`, but it doesn't have an `onEditingChanged` option.

This is my text field:

```swift
struct CustomTextField : View {
    @Binding var text : String
    @State private var isEditing = false
    @State var isDisabled = false
    
    init(text : Binding<String>, isDisabled : Bool = false ){
        self._text = text
        self.isDisabled = isDisabled
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $text, onEditingChanged: {
            isEditing = $0
        })
        .padding(8)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4))
        .background (
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4)
                .stroke(isEditing ? Color("Accent") : Color("Gray"), lineWidth: isDisabled ? 0 : 1)

        )
    }
}
```

I thought of adding a tap gesture recognizer, but it will only detect when I click, not when I leave the text editor.

Is there a way to detect the focus state of a `TextEditor`?

Comment: Not going to leave this as an answer, because I'm not 100% confident, but my guess is that you'll have to wrap `UITextView`

Comment: Thanks, again, @jnpdx. I'll look into doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the familiar bad news '*@available*', you can use the `focused` modifier, available from **iOS 15**.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var text = "Hello focused!"
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text: $text)
            .focused($isFocused)
            .foregroundColor(isFocused ? .red : .black)
    }
}
```

Note:

1. This does not work in the canvas preview, run on Simulator.
2. This is a simple use of `FocusState`. `FocusState` has many [more options](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/focusstate).